# External regressors in mean or variance equation of AR(1)-GARCH(1,1)?

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive, garch

What is the difference between entering my external regressors in the mean equation and entering them in the variance equation in an AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) model? I get more explanatory results with the external regressors in the variance equation than in the mean, but am not sure as to what the actual difference is. I am modelling returns (the dependent variable) and the external regressors are variables (in time $t$) that should affect the return.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41509/what-is-the-difference-between-garch-and-arma)? It is not a direct answer but should give you a hint.

Answer (score 3):

An AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) model without external regressors is 
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
\mu_t &= \varphi_1 y_{t-1}, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d(0,1). \\
\end{aligned}
It specifies the **entire conditional distribution** of the variable: its conditional mean, conditional variance, and density (its location given by the mean and its scale determined by the variance): $y_t\sim d(\mu_t,\sigma_t^2)$.

If you include regressors in the **conditional mean** model only (the equation for $\mu_t$), for different values of regressors you get different fitted and predicted values of $\mu_t$. Hence, you get different point forecasts (location shifts) but the same variance (and density, adjusted for the location) forecasts around the different points.

If you include regressors in the **conditional variance** model only (the equation for $\sigma_t^2$), for different values of regressors you get different fitted and predicted values of $\sigma_t^2$. Hence, you get different variance (and thus density) forecasts (scale shifts) around the same point forecasts.

If you include regressors in both the **conditional mean** *and* the **conditional variance** models, for different values of regressors you get different fitted and predicted values of $\mu_t$ *and* $\sigma_t^2$. Hence, you get different point forecasts (location shifts) *and* different variance forecasts (scale shifts) around the different point forecasts. So the density both shifts *and* scales due to the effects of regressors.

Comment: as you suggested to ping you back on Sunday, and my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420946/writing-the-likelihood-and-conditional-variance-in-a-armax-model-or-regression-w) is strictly related to this topic above, I would be extremely grateful if you could check this question.

Comment: I re-express the question by summarizing as follows so that, if you want to save time, you can skip the reading. In two words, the question is: when I have external regressors and have to write the model likelihood, do I have to express the likelihood conditioning on both the info set at time t-1 and the external regressors? Or the likelihood is just expressed conditioning on t-1 alone as for the typical case with no external regressors? Many thanks in advance Richard