# Predicting 2 steps ahead with ARMA

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

How does one forecast 2 steps ahead in an ARMA model? If my training data is $y_1, ..., y_T$, and I have an ARMA(1, 1) model, then I have

$$\hat{y}_{T+1} = \alpha*y_T + \beta*(\hat{y}_T-y_T)$$

but what about $\hat{y}_{T+2}$? How would I know what to multiply $\beta$ by, because I don't know the error at time step $T+1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multistep prediction interval for ARMA(p,q) process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352840/multistep-prediction-interval-for-armap-q-process). (The linked thread covers your case even though its title does not immediately suggest so.)

Comment: So in this example, the \beta term would disappear, if we plug the forecast for T+1 in place of the true value, right?

Comment: Right. The point forecast of a future error term is zero.

Comment: perfect, thanks!