# Forecasting the conditional variance of AR(p)-GARCH(1,1) model

Tags: autoregressive, garch, volatility

How can I derive forecasting formula for the conditional variance $h_{t+k}$, $k\geq1$ for AR(p)-GARCH(1,1)?

Comment: Might [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352654) be a duplicate? Or perhaps [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/73540)?

Comment: Hint: The conditional mean model (in this case AR(p)) does not play a role when forecasting the conditional variance. The cond. var. forecast is thus derived from the cond. var. equation specified by GARCH(r,s). Multiple-step-ahead cond. var. forecast can be found in a time series textbook that covers GARCH models. Try e.g. Tsay ["Analysis of Financial Time Series"](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Analysis+of+Financial+Time+Series%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780470414354) or  Zivot ["Practical issues in the analysis of univariate GARCH models"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-71297-8_5).