# What are the differences between GARCH/ARCH and LSTM for time series prediction?

Tags: time-series, model, garch, lstm

Can somebody explain in-detailed differences between the GARCH/ARCH model and LSTM for time-series prediction and how the model works under the hood?

Comment: See ["What is the difference between GARCH and ARMA?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41509/) for the ARIMA / GARCH part. (I am not saying this is a duplicate, just a relevant thread.)