# Is it possible to create ARCH-GARCH model using MA(q) or ARMA(0,0,q) as conditional mean equation?

Tags: time-series, arima, garch

I tried to create ARCH-GARCH as conditional variance equation but the result of conditional mean analysis (I use ARIMA) shows MA(q) or ARMA(0,0,q) fits conditional mean modelling.
Data has ARCH effects.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have a model where the conditional mean equation is MA(q) while the conditional variance equation is some type of (G)ARCH. Statistically speaking, the conditional mean equation tells us nothing about what the conditional variance equation should be, nor the other way around.

Check out ["What is the difference between GARCH and ARMA?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41509/what-is-the-difference-between-garch-and-arma) for a broader overview.